# UNABLE to run JNLP file under Windows

Tags: java, windows, windows-10, jnlp

I am issuing the following command

```
C:\Users\Dmitry\Downloads>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javaws.exe" kitchen-sink.jnlp
```

`kitchen-sink.jnlp` is downloaded from here: https://pivot.apache.org/demos/kitchen-sink.jnlp

and nothing happens.

How to run JNLP files under Windows?

**UPDATE**

I emphasize: NOTHING happens. I would screenshot error dialogs if they were. But there are none.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information (which you should know, given your reputation score).  What does “unable to run” mean?  Do you keep losing consciousness or something?  What happens when you try to run it?  What output are you seeing?  If Web Start is displaying a failure dialog, include the entire stack trace from the second tab in your question.

Comment: In addition to the advice of @VGR. *"UNABLE to run JNLP file **under Windows"*** What's Windows got to do with it? Does it run OK on *nix and OS X? If you've not tested on those OS', the OS is more than likely irrelevant.

Comment: @VGR nothing happens, I said. No error messages, no failure dialogs, no blackouts, no explosions. Just nothing. As if you didn't run the program.

Comment: Have you tried running with the `-verbose` option?